# Any restriction using Word COM objects in SSH session to Windows?

Tags: powershell, ssh, com

Can we use WinWord COM objects from PowerShell in an SSH session and what are the restrictions, if any?

Let's take an example. I have a PowerShell script which manipulates a Word file ([link here if you really need it](https://github.com/tsduck/tsduck/blob/master/doc/build-user-guide-pdf.ps1)). This script works well when run inside a Windows session. However, when I am logged on the Windows system using SSH, same user as the Windows session, this script no longer works.

The meaningful initialisation sequence is:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $False
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($DocIn)
$properties = $doc.CustomDocumentProperties
```

When the script is run in an SSH session, the document is correctly opened (`$word` and `$doc` are not `$null`). However, `$properties` is `$null`. This is not the case when the script is run inside a Windows session. So, we cannot say that using Word as COM object does not work since the document seems open (and a WINWORD.EXE process is created). But the behaviour is different and limited (useless in my case).

Any explanation? Any guidelines to use Word in PowerShell scripts outside a Windows session, from a remote session?

Comment: I think the issues you are facing are not related to SSH itself but to the type of the session (network logon, not an interactive session) - see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: Thanks @Toni, it seems to be the right pointer. You are right, this is not a matter of SSH but server access in general. In short, Microsoft wrote dozens of millions of lines of code in Windows and Office and you can't even run a script over the network...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in a comment from @Toni, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

In short, it is not possible to run automation scripts for Office using a server access connection (SSH or other).